# Is it better to say “croire en” or “croire dans” something

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Is it better to say “je crois en” or “je crois dans?”

Answer (score 4):

Je crois en. The other form does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

My French book, actually created in France says:

> Ne croyez-vous pas dans l’au-delà

Though, it is a pun for (l’eau de là) because the other person preferred “le vin d’ici” as the two were at a restaurant. So would this phrase have been included for the pun?

Answer (score 1):

***Je crois en*** is much more common and is the only possible form when there is no article following, e.g. ***je crois en*** Dieu but <s>***je crois dans*** Dieu</s> or <s>***je crois à*** Dieu</s> are impossible.

When there is an article, there are case where ***dans*** might be used, e.g.:

> ***je crois en*** sa capacité à réussir ses examens.
>   ***je crois dans*** sa capacité à réussir ses examens.
>   ***je crois à*** sa capacité à réussir ses examens.

The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croire) states ***croire dans*** is used for ***croire en le*** or before plural:

> *Noter également la forme **croire dans**, contraction de croire en le ou, devant un nom plur., croire en les.*

but provides no examples.